# Xcode will not recognize GoogleAPIClientForREST?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift

I am completely new to Apple computers so I might be doing something completely wrong, but my app is not recognizing that there is a module "GoogleAPIClientForREST." It said that it was installed in the terminal so I am not sure what is going on here.

I have followed the steps on the link above three times, every time there is no issue installing it but it will not recognize it.What could I have possibly done wrong?

This is what I entered in my terminal:

```
cd desktop/QuickstartApp


cat << EOF > Podfile &&
platform :ios, '7.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'QuickstartApp' do
    pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Sheets', '~> 1.1.1'
    pod 'GTMOAuth2', '~> 1.1.4'
end
EOF
pod install &&
open QuickstartApp.xcworkspace
```

In my code, I got two errors (refer to the link above for the full code)

```
import GoogleAPIClientForREST
```

- Gives "No Such module 'GoogleAPIClientForREST'

  if let authorizer = service.authorizer,
          canAuth = authorizer.canAuthorize where canAuth {
          listMajors()
- Gives "Expected 'let' in conditional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run `pod install` and then opened the `.xcworkspace` file?

Comment: Yes, but apparently when I typed "open QuickstartApp.xcworkspace," it did not open it. I opened it manually and it seems to be working. google's code is a hot mess (probably outdated, idk), but its recognizing the library now. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 1):

**2018 - Xcode 9.2**

This is probably solved by now but I had a similar issue yesterday and in my case, I had to go to the Pods project and under **Build Settings** > **Build Active Architecture Only** set both debug and release to "**No**".

Make sure you do that on the *Pods project*, not your main app's project.

Hope this can helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding $(inherited) in the Framework Search paths.